# Modulous errors Help C C#

Tags: c#, c

I'm having MAJOR difficulties with this modulo. The C version outputs what I want but not the correct value. My C# outputs what I don't want, but the correct value. How can I get C# version to output C version?

C

```
typedef unsigned long long u64;
typedef unsigned char u8;
static u64 pfd_calculate_hash_table_entry_index(const char *file_name) {
    u64 hash, len, i;

    if (!file_name)
        return -1;

    len = strlen(file_name);
    hash = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        hash = (hash << 5) - hash + (u8)file_name[i];
    printf( "%X ", hash);
    printf( "mod ");
    printf( "%X ", 0x39);
    printf( "= %X\n", hash % 0x39 );
    return hash % 0x39;
}
```

C#

```
public ulong pfd_calculate_hash_table_entry_index(char[] file_name)
{
    uint hash, len, i;
    hash = 0;
    len = (uint)Array.IndexOf(file_name, '\0');
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        hash = (hash << 5) - hash + (byte)file_name[i];
    MessageBox.Show(hash.ToString("X") + " mod 0x39 = " + (hash % 0x39).ToString("X"));
    return ((ulong)hash % 0x39);
}
```

C#

```
#1: char[] file_name = "PARAM.SFO";
#2: char[] file_name = "RAGE.SAV"
```

C

```
#1: char* file_name = "RAGE.SAV";
#2: char* file_name = "PARAM.SFO"
```

C Hashes

```
#1: 0x319FFDA7
#2: 0x1A8C4B5B
```

C# Hashes

```
#2: 0x319FFDA7
#1: 0x1A8C4B5B
```

C Output

```
#1: 0x319FFDA7 % 0x39 = 0x21;
#2: 0x1A8C4B5B % 0x39 = 0x8;
```

C# Output

```
#1: 0x319FFDA7 % 0x39 = 0xA;
#2: 0x1A8C4B5B % 0x39 = 0xE;
```

pics...

C

[image: http://puu.sh/3dT5L/52ababeccf.png]

C#

[image: http://puu.sh/3dT6P/62b911c102.png]

Comment: You should be able to reproduce this with a short but complete program in each language which *just* uses a hard-coded value. The body of the code in each case should be about 5 lines if that. That would be a lot easier to diagnose. Also, we don't know what you're actually trying to achieve - *why* is the result from C the one you want? What's it meant to be?

Comment: That's my point: get rid of the thousands of lines of code until you can reproduce the problem in a *very small* program in each language. The code you're showing *implies* that modulus arithmetic works differently in the two languages. That should be demonstrable without any reference to the rest of the code. Trying to demonstrate it is likely to massively help you. One thing to note: you probably want `ulong` in the C# code, to match `u64` in the C code. (I'd also point out that the C# code is non-idiomatic in terms of naming, variable declaration location etc.)

Comment: I don't see why that should be the best you can simplify it at all. You should be able to just include the hashes themselves. *At least* say what the filename is so we can try to reproduce it. I strongly suspect that the only problem here is using `uint` instead of `ulong`, but I can't reproduce it because you haven't given us enough information.

Comment: Well, you've updated with more results - but not short but complete code. You see, I suspect that `hash` actually *isn't* 0x319FFDA7 in the C code - I suspect that's only showing the last 32 bits of it. I suspect that if `hash` were really that number, you would see the same mod result as in C#. You would be able to see this if you'd create a short but complete program to demonstrate the problem. I'm afraid I don't have time to keep going on this. I've given you my guess about what the problem is and how to fix it, but I can't keep repeating that we need a way of reproducing it.

Comment: Ah, now we've got the filename, which will help.

Comment: "%X" param only is 32 bits and not 64bits?

Comment: I suspect so. I've got the answer though... writing it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. As I thought, this is a problem with the mismatch between `u64` in C and `uint` in C#, which is then confused by bad diagnostic code in the C version.

This is easy to demonstrate in a short but complete C# program:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ShowHash("PARAM.SFO");
        ShowHash("RAGE.SAV");
    }

    static void ShowHash(string name)
    {
        uint hash = 0;
        foreach (char c in name)
        {
            hash = (hash << 5) - hash + (byte) c;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("0x{0:X} mod 0x39 = {1:X}", hash, hash % 0x39);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0x1A8C4B5B mod 0x39 = E
0x319FFDA7 mod 0x39 = A
```

Change the type of `hash` from `uint` to `ulong` and we get:

```
0x3FC01A8C4B5B mod 0x39 = 8
0x21B319FFDA7 mod 0x39 = 21
```

So to get the right modulus, you *don't* want the value 0x1A8C4B5B - you want 0x3FC01A8C4B5B. If you had written a short but complete C program which actually started off with 0x1A8C4B5B, you'd have seen it give the same result as the C# code.

As another point, this code is pretty much assuming ASCII filenames... is that definitely going to be valid for you?

Comment: It's ANSI but yeah! Thanks man! I'm guessing %X only does 32 bits instead of 64. Explains my difficulties! +1'd

Comment: @user1594121: It may be ANSI in the C code, but in the C# code you're casting a UTF-16 code unit, so you may well end up getting different results for non-ASCII characters.